# iOS image is displayed in simulator but not on the device

Tags: ios, imageview

I have side menu something like this:

[image]

On the simulator it all works great. But when I build on my iPhone 7, the image is not shown.

[image]

I use static table view for side menu and not a xib. I tried creating an outlet for the image and change it in `viewDidLoad`, tried deleting the imageView and creating again, changing image name, downloading new image, nothing. Only this picture is not displayed every time.

```
    class SideMenuVC: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var clientsImage: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        clientsImage.image = UIImage(named: "сlientsIcon.png")

    }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Show relevant code or however you actually setup the image. Keep in mind that file names are case sensitive on real iOS devices.

Comment: I just do it in Storyboard but also i try create outlet . Add code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the file you are using is included in the **"Copy Bundle Resources"** section of your Project's **"Build Phases"** tab.

A better practice to add image assets is to always make the Image Asset in your Project's **Assets.xcassets** folder.

Inside create 'New Image Set' and assign the image into 2x if you have only 1 size for all sized devices otherwise create all sizes required and then just use the same code or via storyboard assign the image. Example below:

[image: Create an Image Set in your Assets]

Use the following code then to set the image if you wish to do that using code:

```
clientsImage.image = UIImage(named: "сlientsIcon")
```

Do not add .png with Image Set name when creating. As you can see an Image Asset in the screenshot named 'locationMarker'. The PNG is placed inside the asset.

Answer (score 0):

Some times it's a cache, try clear Xcode cache, delete the app and try again